# Javascript alert variable, [Object htmlDivElement] error?

Tags: forms, variables, alert

I have made a simple form with a yes and a no checkbox for ram, i want it so that when i press yes it says 5 in an alertbox, and when i press no it says 0  but currently when i hit submit it comes up [Object htmlDivElement]  in the alertbox.

```
<script>

 function alertprice() {            // this will be called on submit of the form
 alert (runningtotal);           // alert the value in variable running total
 }


function totalprice () {                    // function totalprice will set runningtotal depending on boxes ticked
    if(document.getElementById('ramyes').checked) {
        var runningtotal = "5"
            return runningtotal;
}else if(document.getElementById('ramno').checked) {
        var runningtotal = "0"
            return runningtotal;
}
}
          </script>
```

and the html

```
<form name="theForm" action="shop.html" method="post" onSubmit="checkWholeForm(theForm); return alertprice()">
                <h2>Upgrade RAM to "4GB-Kit GEIL Evo One PC3-12800 DDR3-1600 CL9"?</h2>

        <h3>
            <input type="radio" name="ram" value="yes" id="ramyes">yes<br>
            <input type="radio" name="ram" value="no" id="ramno">no     
        </h3>
```

Comment: You're going to have to post more, at least the places where you call these functions.

Comment: You forgot to post `checkWholeForm()`. Please try to post *all* the relevant code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call your function totalprice(). For example like this:

```
function alertprice(){
    alert(totalprice());
}
```

Comment: ah i tried this previously but i forgot the double ()), this worked :) thanks!